# Pull data from online file into local variable

Tags: java, android

If I have a textfile online containing a string, how can I pull the data from it and save it into a local String variable?

For example, say there is a file located at www.myserver.com/File.txt and it only contains one line: "12345"

How can I have my app read the file, and save the "12345" as a string variable that can be used within the app?

Comment: Do you have direct access to the machine, or are you expecting to connect to a webserver on www.mysever.com to try to read the file (i.e. where the webserver can provide the file)?

Comment: I just want to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use URL class to read a file which is not located in your device.
Like this:

```
try {
URL url = new URL("http://www.myserver.com/File.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String textVal;
while((textVal=in.readLine())!=null){ // saving the text in string variable

 }
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
in.close(); }
```

Comment: Im trying to use this within an onclick listener, but im getting a force close when clicking the button. http://pastebin.com/2nsxmJz1

Comment: Post your source code. And make sure you have the permissions to access a resource on the internet in your projects's manifest file. I've edited my answer, check to see if it works. Accept the answer if it does.

Comment: You'll want to wrap that in an ASyncTask to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about that.